# C memmove equivalent of for loop - segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, buffer, memmove

I'm implementing ring buffer with dynamic resizing. When tail is behind head, data from the end of the buffer has to be moved to new end of buffer after resize. In order to do so I made following code:

```
memmove(self->broadcaster.events+self->broadcaster.events_head+self->broadcaster.events_size,
              self->broadcaster.events+self->broadcaster.events_head,
              self->broadcaster.events_size-self->broadcaster.events_head);
```

where `self->broadcaster.events_size` is old size (new_size/2). Unfortunately it results in segmentation fault. I thought it's quivalent of this code:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < self->broadcaster.events_size - self->broadcaster.events_head ; ++i)
        self->broadcaster.events[self->broadcaster.events_size+self->broadcaster.events_head+i]=
            self->broadcaster.events[self->broadcaster.events_head+i];
```

but such naive for-loop implementation works properly so it seems I don't know how to use `memmove` properly. How those two pieces of code are different?

Comment: Why does data have to be moved in a ring buffer? Is this an XY question?

Comment: @WeatherVane when ring buffer turns out to be too short often, I'm increasing its size dynamically. If buffer is not continuos (it's looped) then after reallocation of buffer its rear part has to be moved to new end in order to make such ring buffer "continuos" in sense of ring buffer. To depict it: `OO---OO` --(realloc)-> `OO---OO-------` --(memmove)-> `OO----------OO`.

Comment: What is the type of `broadcaster.events`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're only equivalent if `sizeof(*self->broadcaster.events) == 1`.

For clarity, I've replaced `self->broadcaster` with `b` and `events` with `e` and added some whitespace to your code.

```
memmove(b.e + b.e_head + b.e_size, b.e + b.e_head, b.e_size - b.e_head);
```

will copy just `b.e_size - b.e_head` bytes, and the loop:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < b.e_size - b.e_head ; ++i)
        b.e[b.e_size + b.e_head + i] = b.e[b.e_head + i];
```

will copy `(b.e_size - b.e_head) * sizeof *b.e` bytes, because each `b.e[...] = b.e[...]` assignment is moving through `sizeof *b.e` bytes, and each `++i` is advancing the address of `b.e[... + i]` by `sizeof *b.e` bytes.

You'll be best served if you define a macro:

```
#define MOVE(dst, src, count)  memmove((dst), (src), (count) * sizeof *(src))
```

and use it instead of `memmove`.

But you can of course just change the last argument of `memmove` to

```
(self->broadcaster.events_size-self->broadcaster.events_head)*sizeof*self->broadcaster.events
```